# ¿Cómo cambiar el tweet a generar?

Tags: android, twitter

Buenas, estoy intentando twittear desde una app, lo cual consigo, pero me interesa que el texto cambie según el `String` que le pase como parámetro.

El problema es que el `builder.text()` funciona la primera vez que se ejecuta, la segunda mantiene lo que se puso la primera vez, por lo que intuyo que no es modificable.

```
Twitter.initialize(this);
        TwitterConfig config = new TwitterConfig.Builder(this)
                .logger(new DefaultLogger(Log.DEBUG))
                .twitterAuthConfig(new TwitterAuthConfig("CONSUMER_KEY", "CONSUMER_SECRET"))
                .debug(true)
                .build();
        Twitter.initialize(config);

        final TweetComposer.Builder builder = new TweetComposer.Builder(this);

        builder.text(text2);
```

Se que `text2` si cambia porque lo muestro por pantalla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pude resolverlo creando el builder cada vez que quiero meter un texto nuevo, sobreescribiendo lo que se ha escrito previamente:

```
{
    final TweetComposer.Builder builder = new TweetComposer.Builder(this);
    builder.text(text2);
    builder.show();
}
```